# How to bind component inside the ui:repeat?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, binding, uirepeat

I am binding the component inside `<ui:repeat>`

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{eTManagedBean.capacity}"  varStatus="tableIndex">
<h:panelGrid binding="#{eTManagedBean.capacity[tableIndex.index].subGrid}" /></ui:repeat>
```

But it showing exception

> ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mdf-portal-web].[Faces
>   Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-11) Servlet.service() for
>   servlet Faces Servlet threw exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   javax.el.ListELResolver.toInteger(ListELResolver.java:409)
>   [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]   at
>   javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:199)
>   [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]   at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:121)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:196)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:257)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1949)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1144)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:518)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:168)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]  at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.richfaces.view.facelets.html.BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.applyNextHandler(BehaviorsAddingComponentHandlerWrapper.java:53)
>   [richfaces-components-ui-4.3.5.Final.jar:4.3.5.Final]     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:195)

and when i am trying to access from the  `var`

```
<h:panelGrid id="mainGrid1"  binding="#{item.subGrid}" />
```

then it end up with

> ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/mdf-portal-web].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-10) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/TermCapacityCreation.xhtml @74,28 binding="#{item.subGrid}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'item' resolved to null
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1949) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1144) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]

While in my class i already created object with `get/set` method

```
public class CapacityVO{
 //Other variable 
 private HtmlPanelGrid subGrid;
//get,set() method as well
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is strange, hoever common for JSF implementations. Recently, in pre2.0 times, I had used `<a4j:repeat>` to overcome such issues. Now I suppose it is better to use `<c:forEach>` — it will simply work.

This happens due to state saving in implementation of  ui:repeat as render-time component.